# How to get the bcc information in email header using PHP mailer script

Tags: php

I am using php mailer script for sending emails in my project. When i send mail with bcc using the below code

```
$mail->AddBCC(test@test.com)
```

The email received by test@test.com user but information content showed in the header of the email received doesn’t show BCC information as below.

```
Bcc: test@test.com
```

How can I achieve it.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Erm, that's what puts the B in BCC. B for Blind....

Comment: BCC stands for Blind Carbon Copy ... with other words.. you will never see it who it is send too... you could do a CC, but i doubt you want the receipiant to see to which account it get send too.

Comment: I want the BCC person to see his email in "Bcc:test@test.com"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BCC information is automatically moved from BCC to RCPT field by the SMTP server. You will not see BCC fields in the recipient's mailbox.

You will find a good answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2750359/239599

Comment: Hi  Naivists  thank you very much  for  quick replay .Bcc information can viewed from the bcc  mailbox as similar to gmail. how can i achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use mailhog, click on the `Show headers` an you will see the `cc` and `bcc`

[image]