# Using curl to send email

Tags: linux, email, curl, command-line, gmail

How can I use the curl command line program to send an email from a gmail account?

I have tried the following:

```
curl -n --ssl-reqd --mail-from "<sender@gmail.com>" --mail-rcpt "<receiver@server.tld>" --url smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465 -T file.txt
```

With file.txt being the email's contents, however, when I run this command I get the following error:

```
curl: (67) Access denied: 530
```

Is it possible to send an email from an account that is hosted by a personal server, still using curl? Does that make the authentication process easier?

Comment: Can't you send email thru a local (or near to you) SMTP server?

Comment: Indeed I could, but that was not the question.

Comment: It does not surprise me that Google forbids using their SMTP server as spam proxies...

Comment: I think it is possible I just don't think I have my syntax correct.  I have attempted slight variations of what I posted and have gotten different feedback such as prompting me for a password, but the email still fails...

Comment: I believe Gmail will require you to use Oauth for authentication.  This won't be easy with curl.  You can see Google's Oauth documentation at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_protocol .

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```sh
curl --ssl-reqd \
  --url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465' \
  --user 'username@gmail.com:password' \
  --mail-from 'username@gmail.com' \
  --mail-rcpt 'john@example.com' \
  --upload-file mail.txt
```

*mail.txt* file contents:

```
From: "User Name" <username@gmail.com>
To: "John Smith" <john@example.com>
Subject: This is a test

Hi John,
I’m sending this mail with curl thru my gmail account.
Bye!
```

Additional info:

1. I’m using `curl` version 7.21.6 with SSL support.
2. You don't need to use the `--insecure` switch, which prevents `curl` from performing SSL connection verification. See [this online resource](//curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) for further details.
3. It’s considered a bad security practice to pass account credentials thru
   command line arguments. Use `--netrc-file`. See [the documentation](//ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-netrc).
4. You must [turn on access](//www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) for less secure apps or the newer [App passwords](//myaccount.google.com/apppasswords).

Comment: Thanks man.  That totally did the trick.  Any recommendations for doing this more securely.  I want to have a cron job on my server run a script that will send out emails at a specific time.  I figured a curl command would be the easiest but not the most secure.  I am not very familiar with smtp servers and such, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I'd want to use something like that to send automated mails from a bash script while avoiding password in the command line ?
I've noticed that if you omit the password part you get prompted so I could use expect to deal with that but is there a simpler approach to have curl read from a redirect ? or maybe even an environment variable ?

Comment: oh ... I get it ... yo can put credentials in .netrc

Comment: The command is successfully executed but the email arrives empty, no content.

Comment: @louigi600, I wouldn't use a .netrc file. However, you could use the `--netrc-file` parameter, and then use bash subshell redirection. E.g. `curl --netrc-file <(printf '%s' "${MY_CREDENTIALS}"` ... `bash` will create a file descriptor to feed the credential data in, and (I think) the data won't even touch disk.

Comment: @MichaelMol Could you please provide the whole command, at least the part where `--netrc-file` should be printed? Is it like: `curl --user --netrc-file <(printf '%s' "${MY_CREDENTIALS}"` ?

Comment: @khashashin, SO won't let me edit my comment, but I see I had a syntax error. Try something like `--netrc-file <(printf '%s' "${MY_CREDENTIALS}")` somewhere in your command. (My original comment was missing a closing paren.

Comment: How about multiple recipients?

Comment: what if I want to send the message directly from the command line, not from a file?

Comment: How to attach a file to the email ?

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution to this problem. Using with [google app passwords](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords), I combined it with default carrier address I found at [this service](https://freecarrierlookup.com) to send myself SMS texts from a cron job. @bambam

Answer (score 10):

if one wants to send mails as carbon copy or blind carbon copy:

```
curl --url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465' --ssl-reqd \
  --mail-from 'username@gmail.com' --mail-rcpt 'john@example.com' \
  --mail-rcpt 'mary@gmail.com' --mail-rcpt 'eli@example.com' \
  --upload-file mail.txt --user 'username@gmail.com:password' --insecure
```

```
From: "User Name" <username@gmail.com>
To: "John Smith" <john@example.com>
Cc: "Mary Smith" <mary@example.com>
Subject: This is a test

a BCC recipient eli is not specified in the data, just in the RCPT list.
```

Comment: No, that's incorrect, or at least dubious; there is no need for the email message to contain an explicit Bcc: header. As far as SMTP is concerned, the message headers are just data, and the *actual* recipients are specified by other means (in this case, by specifying `--mail-rcpt` multiple times if you want to send to multiple recipients).

Comment: yes. it was incorrect thanks for pointing out! i am correcting the answer. see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750211/sending-bcc-emails-using-a-smtp-server.

Answer (score 3):

Crate a simple `email.conf` file like so

```
Username:   hi@example.com
Password:   OKbNGRcjiV
POP/IMAP Server:    mail.example.com
```

And simply run `sendmail.sh`, like so after making it executable (`sudo chmod +x sendmail.sh`)

```
./sendmail.sh
```

Code

```
#!/bin/bash

ARGS=$(xargs echo  $(perl -anle 's/^[^:]+//g && s/:\s+//g && print' email.conf) < /dev/null)
set -- $ARGS "$@";  

declare -A email;
email['user']=$1
email['pass']=$2
email['smtp']=$3
email['port']='587';
email['rcpt']='your-email-address@gmail.com';


email_content='From: "The title" <'"${email['user']}"'>
To: "Gmail" <'"${email['rcpt']}"'>
Subject: from '"${email['user']}"' to Gmail
Date: '"$(date)"'

Hi Gmail,
'"${email['user']}"' is sending email to you and it should work.
Regards
';


echo "$email_content" | curl -s \
    --url "smtp://${email['smtp']}:${email['port']}" \
    --user "${email['user']}:${email['pass']}" \
    --mail-from "${email['user']}" \
    --mail-rcpt "${email['rcpt']}" \
    --upload-file - # email.txt


if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    echo;
    echo 'okay';
else
    echo "curl error code $?";
    man curl | grep "^ \+$? \+"
fi
```

[more](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-smtp)

Comment: This works fine, I'm on Ubuntu 16 and need to attach a file. How to do this ?

Comment: @cwhisperer Did you try this one [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728856/4643584](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728856/4643584)

Answer (score 1):

Mind that the form of mail.txt seems to be important / CRLF for win, LF for Linux, special characters etc.

Finally after struggling 2 hours, it works for me for GMX (they tell their SMPT port to be 587 - and further down in small letters the hint: "also 465 can be used with SSL"):

UNDER Linux (TinyCore Linux on Raspberry 3B+ with curl.tcz installed):

```
curl --ssl-reqd --url 'smtps://mail.gmx.net:465' --user 'mymail@gmx.at:mymailPassword' --mail-from 'mymail@gmx.at' --mail-rcpt 'mymail@gmx.at' --upload-file mail.txt
```

UNDER Windows:

```
curl --ssl-reqd --url "smtps://mail.gmx.net:465" --user "mymail@gmx.at:mymailPassword" --mail-from "mymail@gmx.at" --mail-rcpt "mymail@gmx.at" --upload-file mail_win.txt
```

with mail.txt:

```
From: "User Name" <mymail@gmx.at>
To: "John Smith" <mymail@gmx.at>
Subject: This is a test

Hi John,
Im sending this mail with curl thru my gmx account.
Bye!
```

Comment: This works fine, but how to attach a file ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if Perl's "`system()`" function is used to execute the `curl` command, each argument 'word' is a separate item in the argument array, and words **must NOT be quoted**.

Also note that if sending via Gmail after May 30, 2022, the gmail account must be set up with 2-factor authentication and then you must create an "App Password".  The App Password is a long character string that acts as an alternative password and replaces the usual password on the "`--user`" parameter.