# Using curl to send an email over gmx

Tags: curl

What specific settings are required to send an email using a `GMX` Account?

I tried this [Using curl to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722556/using-curl-to-send-email).
But somehow I cannot connect to the server:

```
* About to connect() to mail.gmx.net port 465 (#0)
*   Trying 212.227.17.190...
* 0x8001f100 is at send pipe head!
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x80057238; line 1032 (connection #0)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:14 --:--:--     0
```

Answer (score 0):

The firewall was the bad guy... Disable and it works!