# CURL Sendmail via bash

Tags: bash, email, curl, smtp

Hi i've a problem whit this code:

```
# up here there's more code

echo "Password changed" $(date) > lez.txt
curl -n --ssl-reqd --mail-from "me@lupetto.sh" --mail-rcpt "my mail" -T lez.txt --url smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465 --user "example@gmail.com:password"
```

If I run the script I get only a empty mail, but if I do this manually I get my mail.
  Thanks.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722556/using-curl-to-send-email

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's having problems to find the file contents. What about using a [here-string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) to avoid writing a file at all? Change your code to:

```
curl -n --ssl-reqd --mail-from "me@lupetto.sh" --mail-rcpt "my mail" -T - --url smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465 --user "example@gmail.com:password" <<<"Password changed $(date)"
```

Notice the `echo` statement removal, the here-string at the end of the line and the `-T -` to get the file from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

cURL expects that the file to be sent has a empty line on the 1st row

the script below will do that for you

```
##!/bin/sh
# USAGE 
#
# sh emailfile.sh examplefile.log


file="$1"
echo "" > temp | cat "$1" >> temp && mv temp "$1"

wait

curl --url "smtps://smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465" \
     --mail-from "youremail@yahoo.com" \
     --mail-rcpt "dest@domain.com" \
     --user "youremail@yahoo.com:EmailAccountPassword" \
     -T - --silent < "$file"

wait
```