# How to send SMTP request and read response with php curl?

Tags: php, email, curl, smtp, freebsd

I'm trying to send `smtp` request to my `smtp` server installed in `freebsd` and read the successful or fail response?
This is my code :

```
$url = '192.168.1.227:25/';
    $user = 'admin';
    $pass = '123';

    $params = array(
        'User'      => $user,
        'passwor'   => $pass,
        'to'        => 'example1@example.com',
        'subject'   => 'test',
        'html'      => 'body',
        'text'      => 'text',
        'from'      => 'example2@example.com',
      );


    $session = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    $info = curl_getinfo($session);
    curl_close($session);
    echo $response;
    print_r($info);
```

Comment: You can use this example: https://gist.github.com/hdogan/8649cd9c25c75d0ab27e140d5eef5ce2 But in case of error, it seems that you can't got it.

Answer (score 3):

cURL is not the right tool for this. Although it does support [simple SMTP connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069786/3908235), it's generally not designed for more advanced use cases.

cURL is designed for HTTP, where you usually have one request with a bunch of parameters (the HTTP request headers) and one response.¹

SMTP communication however goes more like “ping-pong”. To implement a SMTP client, you would have to work on raw TCP sockets: Write a SMTP command on the socket, read/process the response, write the next command, and so on.

Also, SMTP, as it's currently implemented, has got a lot of quirks and weird side aspects across servers and clients. For example, the PHP/cURL-based approach would not be able to support greylisting, unless you would manage your own queue for temporarily rejected mail.

Unless you have a good reason to do so (and a lot of time, as well as high frustration tolerance), you should use a client library like Swiftmailer together with a real MTA for outgoing mail.

If, on the other hand, you're just curious to play with a raw connection to a mail server, use a tool like `netcat` from the command line and work through a [howto of such a scenario](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/sending-email-netcat).

..

¹ if you leave keep-alive etc. aside for a moment.