# I want to send mail from my server using gmail

Tags: php, email

Here is my smtp code butit gives error

> SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
> SMTP -> FROM SERVER: F 
> SMTP ->
>   ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server: F 
> SMTP -> FROM
>   SERVER:  
> SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server:  SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedLanguage
>   string failed to load: tls
>   Below is my smtp details i am using

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = "*******"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "********"; // SMTP password
$mail->From = "*******"; //do NOT fake header.
$mail->FromName = "test";

$mail->AddAddress($to_email,"test"); // Email on which you want to send mail
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;

$mail->Body = $mail_body;
```

Comment: Have you tried the gmail api [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php) ?

Comment: i have no idea about it. can you just explain in detail?

Comment: just check it please, as there is quite a lot to explain. they have a test at the end, which verifies if you have succeeded or not.

Comment: If `curl` is an option, you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069786/3020926