# Send RCPT TO in C?

Tags: c, curl

I'm newbie in C, how I can connect to remote smtp server and send manually command `RCPT TO` using curl? I'm read curl docs, but not found answer.

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve. `libcurl` is a high level API that should make it easy to perform complex protocol tasks. What about other protocol commands before `RCPT_TO`, what about handling the response? If you really want to send **only** `RCPT_TO` (which doesn't make sense), CURL may not be the right tool.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to implement this in C, see the example on the CURL page
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html

A command line example for sending mail with `curl` you can find on
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069786/10622916

Comment: The example does not show how the RCPT TO commands are executed. Function `curl_easy_perform()` do it hidden.