# Send e-mail via pipelines in Gitlab-CI

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci

does anyone have experience with sending emails via pipelines in gitlab?
i am using gitlab CI/CD for deployment.I have a requirement from a customer,they want:

1. notification by starting a pipeline with started jobs
2. notification at the end of pipeline
3. notification when an error occurred

I am able to send a dummy text email via any SMTP Server or any API Mailing server but my problem is how to include in my email the jobs?I do not want to send a dummy email but an email which includes the jobs/components which are going to be deployed.

Comment: Curious how you sent the "dummy" email?  I'm trying to figure out a similar issue.

Comment: this is easy to achieve,see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722556/using-curl-to-send-email