# How to add addresses to the BCC field using Rebol's SEND function?

Tags: email, smtp, rebol, rebol2

I'm trying to send an email using SEND in Rebol 2:

```
send foo@bar.com "A Message"
```

How do I BCC a second address? I've tried the following without success:

```
send/header foo@bar.com "A Message" make system/standard/email [
    BCC: baz@bar.com
]
```

This still goes to the first recipient, but not the BCC address. Is this a misunderstanding of how BCC works?

*Also, using a custom header no longer copies part of the message for the subject line, but not so worried about that...*

Answer (score 1):

The correct way for BCC is to put the same address to TO as well:

```
send/header [
    test1@example.com test2@example.com
] "A Message" make system/standard/email [
    bcc: test2@example.com
]
```

You TRACE/NET ON to see the difference with and without adding TO.

And here you can find a similar question:

[Sending BCC emails using a SMTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750211/sending-bcc-emails-using-a-smtp-server)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this sends the same message twice to the SMTP server and other recipients can see who's in the BCC line.

Comment: The [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26611044/292969) on that page correctly describes the behaviour I'm looking for. See: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/111395/46291

Comment: I tested the above code, other recipients cannot see the address in BCC. But I think you are right that it sends the same msg twice.

Comment: Some receiving servers will strip the BCC field en route, others won't. It seems the only certain way to prevent it being shared is to strip prior to sending.